# SpriteKit scaling affects physics

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics

I've implemented zooming by rescaling a root "world" node housing all the objects in my game. However, with the smaller size of the world node & children, applying forces now has a greater effect.

Even if I scale forces by the same scaling as my world node, they are still huge and objects go flying.

I've seen some pretty hectic solutions around:

- Scale the scene (but then overlays are scaled too)
- Create a whole new invisible layer that obeys normal physics then a visible layer on top which you scale...

Is there a more straightforward approach to somehow just scale the physics world with the world node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, don't **scale** in order to zoom. Try **resizing** instead.

`myScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;`

And then while zooming:

`myScene.size = CGSizeMake(myScene.size.width + dx, myScene.size.height + dy);`

*[Apple Documentation says:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html)

> Set the scaleMode property to SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill. Sprite Kit automatically resizes the scene so that it always matches the view’s size.

Comment: I've changed my pinching method to scaling, but it still seems like the physics is scaling with it. For two scales I get very different velocities when force is applied to an SKNode. The effect is less than with a scale, but is still apparent. Do you have any idea why this could be??

Comment: Do you mean you changed your method to RESIZING? Because you must avoid scaling. Resizing shouldn't affect physics world the way you described

Comment: And you use the exact same physical properties and forces regardless of the zooming level (not changing them manually)? Right? As said, resizing the scene shouldn't affect the physics world. Also, I'm using this method myself in my games and I don't see any discrepancy. Not even if zooming when physics world is "live".

Comment: Did you find the solution? If not, you could try making a simple code example that reveals the issue and post it here?

Comment: Yeah this did fix it in the end. In your games do you have an HUD? If so do you present it in a separate view or when you scale the scene do you also scale the HUD?

Comment: Glad to hear you got it fixed - I have only one view and one scene. HUD and game world are separate Nodes or "layers". When I resize the scene, I scale the HUD accordingly.

Comment: Oh ok cool. That was the solution I arrived at too, I just thought it might be a bit convoluted

Comment: I have custom SKScene class to which Nodes can subscribe to get periodic calls like update: and onPhysicsSimulated: etc. So, I just overrided the scene's setSize: method and call all subscribers who respond to onSceneSizeChanged: